# Passing variables to an AJAX function through the parameters PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to pass 4 variables through the parameters of the ajax function, but it's not accepting it for some reason. The variables I'm trying to pass are the url, action, id, and the timeout in milliseconds. If anyone know what I'm doing wrong, please correct me. Thank you.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type = "text/javascript"> 

function myAjax(url,action,id,timeout) {
      $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data:{action: action},
           error: function(xhr,status,error){alert(error);},
           success:function(data) {
             document.getElementById( id ).innerHTML = data;
             setTimeout(myAjax, timeout);
           }

      });

}

</script>

<body onload="myAjax('testing.php','call_this','my_div',2000)">

<div id="my_div"></div>

</body>
```

Here's the working version of the code, without passing the variables through the parameters, and instead having them inside the function itself:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type = "text/javascript"> 

function myAjax() {
      $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: 'testing.php',
           data:{action: 'call_this'},
           error: function(xhr,status,error){alert(error);},
           success:function(data) {
             document.getElementById( 'my_div' ).innerHTML = data;
             setTimeout(myAjax, 2000);
           }

      });

}

</script>

<body onload="myAjax()">

<div id="my_div"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes. It did got called. But only once. Then it stops. Period. Even though the timeout is only on 2 seconds. I waited for minutes. It didn't move.

Comment: And what would be the parameter values passed for the subsequent calls? Did you do a `console.log( url )` in the function before the ajax call to see if the second call, if any, passes any value to the function?

Comment: I would re-write the setTimeout function like so: `setTimeout(function() { myAjax(url,action,id,timeout); }, timeout);`

Comment: @PeterKA Ah, yes. That fixed my problem. Thank you. Though if you post your comment as an answer, I will up vote and accept it for future visitors.

Comment: Reposted as answer ... :-) Glad I could help! Enjoy!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re-write the `setTimeout()` call like so:

```
setTimeout(function() { 
    myAjax(url,action,id,timeout); 
}, timeout);
```

Comment: Okay. One more question? If my server only has 100GB of bandwidth, what should I set my timeout as? I don't want to overload my server and crash it, as it happened many times in the past when I didn't know how use timeout correctly.

Comment: Maybe a strategy, if there is, that makes the Ajax call only if server data has changed would be better.

Comment: But how would ajax know that the server data has changed UNLESS they check it first? I wonder if that kind of strategy exist. If so, I so want to know. I think a lot of people would want to know.

Comment: Maybe you may want to ask this as an independent question so as to be fair to it. I know there's an answer out there. A server-side script could be used to update a cookie which can then be monitored by your JS.

Answer (score 1):

The second time it is called (from your `success` handler), you are not passing any parameters to `myAjax()` so it will not have any arguments when it is invoked the second time.

There are a couple ways you can fix that.  One way it to just copy the arguments when you call `myAjax(...)` from within:

```
function myAjax(url,action,id,timeout) {
      $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data:{action: action},
           error: function(xhr,status,error){alert(error);},
           success:function(data) {
             document.getElementById( id ).innerHTML = data;
             setTimeout(function() {
                 myAjax(url, action, id, timeout);
             }, timeout);
           }
      });
}
```

But, you could also make an inner function and then just reference the arguments from the closure like this:

```
function myAjax(url,action,id,timeout) {
      function run() {
          $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: url,
               data:{action: action},
               error: function(xhr,status,error){alert(error);},
               success:function(data) {
                 document.getElementById( id ).innerHTML = data;
                 setTimeout(run, timeout);
               }
          });
      }
      // run the ajax function the first time
      run();
}
```

Comment: @iscattered - check out the second option here that makes use of an inner function and a closure to keep access to your arguments without having to recopy them.

Comment: I have a question? When I changed the parameter name 'action' to any other text, it only executes the function once for some reason. Do you have any idea why? Thanks.

Comment: @iscattered - you'd have to show me exactly what the new code looks like that didn't work.  I can't tell from your description.